# Facial Recognition with OpenCV and Alexa

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to link OpenCV powered by a Raspberry Pi and Alexa together.
The basic idea is to have a camera installed with the Pi, and have it recognise faces along with Alexa for voice commands.
So an example would be a person named Peter, facing the camera and Alexa will say Hi Peter. Or it could be when Peter asks Alexa who am I, Alexa will reply you are Peter. Something alone the lines. I plan to use OpenCV for machine learning so that it recognizes people.

Is this project too ambitious or is it still quite feasible? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is quite feasible. With UV4L supporting WebRTC you can get audio/video streams in real-time from the Raspberry Pi into the browser so that you can process each frame with OpenCV.js and interact with the Alexa services from within the browser itself in standard Javascript. See [this example](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/custom-webapp-with-face-detection/) for face detection.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, but I have a question. What is the purpose of OpenCV.js and how does it help me with my project?

Comment: I think he's assuming you want to do this with a browser-based solution, but it sounds like you prefer to run OpenCV directly from the command line.

Comment: Isn't Alexa a web-based service fundamentally? Then to make it easy I'd develop a web application if possible.